# Split IProgressMonitor Asynchronously

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to create my own `ISearchQuery` that delegates the actual search to a couple other searches. I'm expecting that only one of the other searches will actually find something, that's why I want to run them asynchronously.

However I'm struggeling with how to achieve that goal. The standard way in Eclipse would probably be to use jobs:

```
@Override
public IStatus run(final IProgressMonitor monitor) throws OperationCanceledException {
    for (Delegate delegate : delegates) {
        Job job = new Job(delegate.getName()) {

            @Override
            protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                delegate.run(monitor);
                return Status.OK_STATUS;
            }
        };
        job.schedule();
    }
    return Status.OK_STATUS;
}
```

That's asynchronously alright, but the problem here is that since each job has its own `IProgressMonitor`, the parenting search can't get any information about how the progress is coming along (except for "finished" when the job is done). Also I'm not sure if these jobs even get executed at the same time, from what I've seen they get executed one after the other normally.

I found the [SubMonitor](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FSubMonitor.html) and it looks promissing:

```
@Override
public IStatus run(final IProgressMonitor monitor) throws OperationCanceledException {
    SubMonitor subMonitor = SubMonitor.convert(monitor, delegates.size());
    for (Delegate delegate : delegates) {
        SubMonitor delegateMonitor = subMonitor.split(1);
        delegate.run(delegateMonitor);
    }
    return Status.OK_STATUS;
}
```

However now I'm struggeling with how to get this to work asynchronously.

I might be able to combine both of these approaches, ignoring the job's `IProgressMonitor`, but it feels like cheating.

What is the best way to split a `IProgressMonitor` into asynchronous tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't run into such situation myself, so my thoughts are not backed by practical experience.

My first choice would be to schedule a single Job and share a single progress monitor among all asynchronous tasks. A task would only be allowed to report the amount of work done (i.e. call `worked()`). `beginTask()` and `done()` would only be called from the Job, like sketched in your second snippet.

With the exception of `FutureProgressMonitor`, none of the `IProgressMonitor` implementations that I have come across seems to be thread safe.

Therefore, you would need to implement a thread-safe wrapper.or look into `FutureProgressMonitor` whether that fits.

In addition, the Job would need to wait for all tasks to finish. Maybe returning `Job.ASYNC_FINISH` from the Job's `run()` method also works, but I haven't used that myself so far.